# PIP3 python pip3 does not work or install property

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, version, apt

### PIP3 does not install!

Meanwhile i was setting my vps i tried to install python3 thorugh repositories and it did worked but i wasn't lucky for pip3. please help.

I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I did this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 -V
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip3
pip3 install --upgrade wheel
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

should fix it